# How are 'data' and 'end' events being sent to HTTP server of nodejs from cURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, curl

This code is from "Nodejs in Action" book:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var items = [];

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
            {
                switch (req.method) 
                {
                case 'POST':
                    var item = '';
                    req.setEncoding('utf8');
                    req.on('data', function(chunk)
                        {
                            item += chunk;
                        });
                    req.on('end', function()
                        {
                            items.push(item);
                            res.end('OK\n');
                        });
                    break;
                    
                case 'GET':
                    items.forEach(function(item, i){
                              res.write(i + ') ' + item + '\n');
                            });
                            res.end();
                    break;
                }
            });
```

`.on` works as a slot and waits for an event. In this case the events are 'data' and 'end'.
cURL is being used to send requests to the server.

They have used following commands to sent the requests:

```
$ curl -d 'buy groceries' http://localhost:3000
OK
$ curl -d 'buy node in action' http://localhost:3000
OK
```

**My question is - from where are these events being sent/fired?

I don't see any code emitting 'data' and 'end' events.**

Comment: It's a TCP stream. Each data packet from your router triggers a `data` event. There is only indirect relationship with curl. If you curl form your LAN then most likely the sender's network card is the one splitting the curl requests into multiple TCP packets and that is what causes the network card on the node.js machine to accept multiple packets which cause node.js to generate multiple `data` event...

Comment: .. If you curl to another machine on the internet then other people get involved. Your ISP may split the packets further or even in some cases join packets so your node server may get fewer or more `data` events than what the PC/laptop/raspberryPi/phone/etc that does the curl split the request into..

Comment: As for who is generating the `data` and `done` events. It is your TCP/IP and network card drivers. TCP `done` events in node.js are generated when the socket closes however HTTP `done` events are generated by the HTTP parser when it detects the end of the HTTP request which can either be just two newlines after the header (either `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n`) or when the bytes sent after the header equals the value of the `Content-length` header

Comment: @slebetman Thank you. What would be the way to know the names of the events to write in my code? How would I know that events names are data and end, and not something else? Where should I look for the docs to know these names?

Comment: Look at the documentation. It is documented in https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen which references https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen which says that the socket is of type https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket which lists all the events you can listen to

Comment: @slebetman thank you. I had looked at : 
 nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_method Could not find anything there. Please write your whole explanation with links as an answer.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, I gave you the wrong trail. The docs is a bit hard to read. So `http.CreateServer` says that `The requestListener is a function that is added to the request event` which leads us to https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request which tells us that the first argument is https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage. But IncomingMessage shows only two events.. until we realize that it inherits from `stream.Readable` which leads us to https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable for the rest of the events

Comment: @slebetman Now please gather whatever you think is correct and write that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL doesn’t send events. cURL makes HTTP requests.

The events are generated by code internal to Node.js when data from an HTTP request arrives and when the HTTP request is done.

The events 'data' and 'end' are in the stream API of nodejs:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: What is the way to know the names of these events? 'data' and 'end' events re not in the API : https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_method

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl They are documented in the stream API https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: @DanD thank you for the helpful link. Consider writing an answer